# .is(':visible') does not work in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use `.is(':visible')` method in jquery but it does not work as expected.

[Here is my code snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/gBNcW/)

What did I miss there?

HTML:

```
<div class="str">

    <ul><li>1</li><li><a href="#">hide</a></li></ul>
    <ul><li>2</li><li><a href="#">hide</a></li></ul>
    <ul><li>3</li><li><a href="#">hide</a></li></ul>
    <ul><li>4</li><li><a href="#">hide</a></li></ul>
    <ul><li>5</li><li><a href="#">hide</a></li></ul>
    <ul><li>6</li><li><a href="#">hide</a></li></ul>

    <div class="length"></div>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){

    $('.str ul').find('a').live('click',function(){
       $(this).closest('li').parent().hide();
       var ll= $('.str').find('ul').each(function(){  
           $('.length').text( $('.str').find('ul').is(':visible').length );  
        });   
    });

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use: `$('.str').find('ul:visible').length`

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gBNcW/4/)*

```
$(function(){
    
    $('.str ul').on('click','a',function(){    
       $(this).closest('li').parent().hide();
        
       var visibleUL = $('.str').find('ul:visible').length;      
       $('.length').text( visibleUL );        
       alert(visibleUL );
        
    });
    
});
```

While `.is()` returns a boolean value ( `true / false` ), the `:visible` selector targets the desired elements creating an elements array collection - exactly what you need to return a valid array `length`

Comment: One more thing, now i want to alert its length. when I am doing it giving me 'object object' in alert box. what is did I just wrap this code with alert($('.length').text( $('.str').find('ul:visible').length );)

Comment: @amit you cannot alert an object text. Put your length count into a variable and use it as you want!

Comment: why it is not working when we writing alert($('.length').text( $('.str').find('ul:visible').length );). what is the reason behind

Comment: @amit 'cause you're targeting the `text` property of an object (your `.length` element), not a value. You need to retrieve the **value holded by an object** like: `alert( $('.str').find('ul:visible').length )` without the `$.text()`

Answer (score 4):

The `.is()` method returns `true` or `false`

From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

> Unlike other filtering methods, .is() does not create a new jQuery object.

You should use `find()` or `filter()` not `is()`.

Answer (score 1):

`is(':visible')` returns a boolean, not a jQuery object:

```
// Wrong
if ($selector.is(':visible').length) {

// Right
if ($selector.is(':visible')) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I would change that weird HTML to an actual list, not a bunch of lists with one item each :

```
<div class="str">
    <ul>
        <li>1<br><a href="#">hide</a></li>
        <li>2<br><a href="#">hide</a></li>
        <li>3<br><a href="#">hide</a></li>
        <li>4<br><a href="#">hide</a></li>
        <li>5<br><a href="#">hide</a></li>
        <li>6<br><a href="#">hide</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="length"></div>
</div>​
```

And then do:

```
$(function() {
    $('a', '.str ul').on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('li').hide();
        $('.length').text($('.str ul li:visible').length);
    });
})​;​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gBNcW/3/)